# Error sending file attached with email (HTML + PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms, file, attachment

I am trying to send a mail with a file as attachment. I uploaded the website to 000webhost and when I submit the form it returns some warnings.

This is the code of my HTML form:

```
<form class='contacto' action="../php/enviar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><label>Nombre:</label><input type='text' value='' name="to"></div>
    <div><label>E-Mail:</label><input type='text' value='' name="from"></div>
    <div><label>Asunto:</label><input type='text' value='' name="subject"></div>
    <div><label>Mensaje:</label><textarea rows='6' name="messagehtml"></textarea></div>
    <div><label>Adjuntar archivo:</label><input type="file" name="fileatt"></div>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Enviar Mensaje' id="enviar"></div>
</form>
```

This is the PHP file:

```
<?php
function mail_file( $to, $subject, $messagehtml, $from, $fileatt, $replyto="" ) {
// handles mime type for better receiving
$ext = strrchr( $fileatt , '.');
$ftype = "";
if ($ext == ".doc") $ftype = "application/msword";
if ($ext == ".jpg") $ftype = "image/jpeg";
if ($ext == ".gif") $ftype = "image/gif";
if ($ext == ".zip") $ftype = "application/zip";
if ($ext == ".pdf") $ftype = "application/pdf";
if ($ftype=="") $ftype = "application/octet-stream"; 
// read file into $data var
$file = fopen($fileatt, "w");
$data = fread($file,  filesize( $fileatt ) );
fclose($file);
// split the file into chunks for attaching
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
// build the headers for attachment and html
$h = "From: $from\r\n";
if ($replyto) $h .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$h .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$h .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$h .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$h .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$h .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$h .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$h .= $messagehtml."\r\n\r\n";
$h .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$h .= "Content-Type: ".$ftype."; name=\"".basename($fileatt)."\"\r\n";
$h .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$h .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fileatt)."\"\r\n\r\n";
$h .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$h .= "--".$uid."--";
// send mail
return mail( $to, $subject, strip_tags($messagehtml), str_replace("\r\n","\n",$h) ) ;
}
mail_file("mymail@gmail.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST["messagehtml"], $_POST['from'], $_FILES['fileatt'], "");
?>
```

I changed $_FILE['fileatt'] (near the end of the php code) for $_FILES['fileatt']

Now I got this warnings:

```
Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for Array in
Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
Warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

This look like my code is prepared for more than one file, but I want to use this form to send zero or one files.

Thanks

Comment: get rid of the return, plus you have no `$_FILES` array.

Comment: `$_POST['fileatt']` doesn't exist.  You need to get the file from `$_FILES` (see: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: Yes that was a big mistake, I changed $_POST['fileatt'] for $FILE_['fileatt'], this part is a bit confusing for me

Comment: `$FILE_['fileatt'],` ---`$_FILE['fileatt']` that's incorrect. It's `$_FILES` as already stated, *twice*. Do that, and magic might happen ;-)

Comment: Plus, as for the `return` http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php *"If called from within a function, the return statement immediately **ends** execution of the current function..."* - Something I already said. So your next function won't kick in.

Comment: ¿How i must call the mail_file function?

Comment: `$file = fopen($fileatt, "w");` there is nothing "to" open. You need to declare that variable and using the files array for it.

Comment: @yb_esc: `$_FILES['fileatt']` is actually an array.  It contains info about the uploaded file.  Please see: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php.  You need to do some work before you can use the uploaded file.

Comment: You say that the variable $fileatt is not declared or something like that (sorry, my english isn't very good)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. You may very well see undefined variable(s) notice(s).

Comment: Now I can see this notice: Array to string conversion in

Answer (score -1):

Try with PHPMailer lib: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Code example:

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows sending a message using a local sendmail binary.
 */

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
// Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport
$mail->isSendmail();
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer sendmail test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: can we stick to the question, rather than an alternate?

Comment: I saw some examples with that lib but I don't understand why that codes have the fields filled with data, I want to send the form data as $_POST['from'], etc. May I change the data with the dinamic posts?

Comment: I've read the question: "I am trying to send a mail with a file attachment to."
If the person is failing to send an email with attached file, I informed an alternative method to help solve the need.
If I get "vote down" for trying to help, I will not do this anymore.